# Pause in a bash while loop

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, nano

I am currently given the task to check the content of multiple files manually. I have all the files listed in a text file, line for line (newline at the end of each line), and currently trying to work out a  bash script that Is capable of reading the textfile – line for line and then open them in nano for inspection. 
Problem occurs when I open it in nano – I am currently running linux on win10 as a subsystem, so I only have the terminal available.  My current problem is when I try to do this:

`Cat file |  while read line; do nano “$line”; done`

Minimal working example:

```
mkdir test
cd test
touch {a,v,c}
ls > file
Cat file |  while read line; do nano “$line”; done
```

are all file processed at the same time, or it tries to – it loops over all the files and ends – without allowing me to check the file in nano or allow me to properly close it.

Is possible to somehow pause the while loop while I have the file open In nano ?

Comment: So you are using nano - a text editor, to try and read one line of text from an existing text file? Forgive me, but as there is no autonomy here as such, why not just open the file in nano? Is there some filtering at least? Such as if line contains "foo" ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, you need to show us samples of your files(may be not exact data only samples in code tags), then do let us know the requirement which output you need too please in your post?

Comment: @itChi each line of the textfile is a path to the actual file.

Comment: @user9596253, please add samples in your post by using {} button and let us know then?

Comment: Does it run `nano` at all? Are all the files open at then end, or is each nano window closed immediately after being opened?

Comment: @choroba never reached the end.. It ususally chrashes..

Comment: so something along the lines of `bash -c nano $line` should launch nano in a separate shell. When you quit nano, it should resume the loop.

Comment: I am runing on a linux subsystem.. @itChi  I am indirectly doing what you stated in the terminal

Comment: How does it crash?

Comment: the example above chrashed with the  message: `Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cat file |  while read line; do nano “$line”; done
```

Nano might be trying to interact with you through its standard input, which is the pipeline. Try redirecting its standard input from your TTY:

```
Cat file |  while read line; do nano “$line” < /dev/tty; done
```